# How to connect R Studio to Tableau?

Tags: r, rstudio, tableau-api

I'm trying to connect R Studio to Tableau Desktop to do some data analysis work, but an error has occurred during connection saying: localhost:6311: Connection refused

I'm using MacOS version 10.13.6

Coding on R:

```
install.packages("Rserve")
library(Rserve)
Rserve()
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal with connecting R and tableau?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following parameter to your Rserve() line which will hard-code the port:

```
Rserve(port = 6311)
```

If that doesn't work, it is worth troubleshooting the port with the following command in terminal (telnet might need to be installed as it is not installed by default):

```
telnet localhost 6311
```

the return from the telnet command should be

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Rsrv0103QAP1
```

More information on the above [here](https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/faq.html)

If the command returns a failure, the problem is certainly outside of Tableau.

Some thoughts from there would be to edit the R config file to explicitly accept remote connections.

Comment: Any luck on this? If you figured it out on your own please add an answer and apply green check mark.